# cannot convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to open a gif file, and send its bytes properly to a webbrowser but it throws the exception 'cannot convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly' and frankly I am baffled, because I already converted it to a string.

```
files=open("WebContent/"+fileName,"rb")
#size=os.path.getsize("WebContent/"+fileName)
text=str(files.read())
text=text.encode('UTF-8')
defaultResponseCode="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\nContent-Length: 29696\r\n\r\n"+text
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `text=text.encode('UTF-8')` Now it's no longer a string...

Comment: Ohhhh so i should just do 'text.encode('UTF-8')'?

Comment: Why convert to string? You don't need that. Your `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header claims to be "binary", hence no encoding has been applied on the data. Send the image just as you read it from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to convert bytes (file opened with `'rb'` mode) to string:

```
text = str(files.read())
```

change above line to this:

```
text = files.read().decode(encoding='change_to_source_file_encoding')
```

then you can convert unicode string to utf-8 byte string with:

```
text = text.encode('UTF-8')
```

And if source encoding is utf-8 you can just pass byte string from `files.read()` to your result string without senseless decode/encode steps (from utf-8 bytes to string and again to  utf-8 bytes)...

update: try with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

```
url = 'url'
files = {'file': open("WebContent/"+fileName, 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

**update 2:**

**According to content-type in response header** (`... Content-Type: image/gif ...`) **you have data with needed format just after** `files.read()` **whithout any encoding/decoding!**

Comment: @user1564622 try now, you are using python3?

Comment: I'm confused -- you should either read this as a string and use it as a string or read it as bytes and use it as bytes. Why both?

Comment: @user1564622 source file in utf-8 encoding?, try to change encoding or decoding with errors='ignore': text = files.read().decode(encoding='utf8', 'ignore')

Comment: No I mean the methodology doesn't make sense. You've having him read a file as bytes, then decode to string based on utf-8 encoding, then re-encoding that string to bytes, then sending out. @user1564622, skip the `str(files.read())` call if you only need to sent it to your browser as bytes, and just send `files.read()`. If you need the plaintext string, save it to a different variable instead using `files.read.decode(encoding='utf8')` as ndpu suggested.

Comment: OK, bottom line, can someone show me read a file and send it correctly in http

Comment: If it's a gif, you should not be bothering with strings at all!!

Answer (score 0):

For those primarily interested in Popen rather than psql, here's a debugged working python3 script, based the original Popen question, and incorporating provided suggestions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# print a list of postgresql databases via psql
import subprocess

username = "postgres"
dbname = "postgres"

p = subprocess.Popen(
  args = ['psql', '-qAt', '-U', username, '-d', dbname],
# args = ['psql', '-qAt', '-d', dbname], # with adequate user permissions
  stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
  stdout = subprocess.PIPE
)
sql = b"SELECT datname FROM pg_database;"

dbs = p.communicate(b"SELECT datname FROM pg_database;")[0].split(b'\n')

for db in dbs:
  print("%s" % db.decode("utf-8"))

p.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3+ I was getting similar problem, and I removed `text.encode("utf-8")` and used `text.strip()`.

```
text = text.strip()
```